# Plotting barplot category-wise in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a dataframe containing columns code, year and number_of_dues. I want to plot barplot having year on x axis and no of claims for each year on y axis for each code in one after after subplot fashion. please help me.
Sample data is given below.

```
Code Year   No_of_dues
1     2016   100
1     2017   200
1     2018   300
2     2016   200
2     2017   300
2     2018   500
3     2016   600
3     2017   800
3     2018
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Your post seems to be missing your minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    df.groupby(['Code', 'Year'])['No_of_dues'].sum().to_frame().plot.bar()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some explanation to your code: why and how does it solve the problem? What do the individual parts do?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

just use seaborn.
set your x and y axes, and hue by the class you want to cohort by